# Proper handling of vertex deletion in AWS Neptune Gremlin Python

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

Deleting a vertex in AWS Neptune using gremlin_python throws an error, even though the vertex is *actually deleted* (cannot find it when I query for it later).

Is my vertex deletion query wrong?

`delete_vertex_q = "g.V(%s).drop().next()"%(v_id)`
`delete_vertex_r = eval(delete_vertex_q)`

after that when i try to find the vertex again:
`print(g.V('<vertex_id>').next())`
I get a `StopIteration` error.

How should I properly handle deletion and checking of vertices in **AWS Neptune Gremlin**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to think of traversals as a stream and when that stream is empty and you try to get the next one an error will occur. If you are sending scripts to Neptune then `g.V(id).hasNext()` is the syntax that will get you a boolean result. If you are using gremlin-python and writing Gremlin in native Python then you will need to do something like:

```
len(g.V(id).toList()) == 0
```

or perhaps:

```
g.V(id).count().next() == 0
```

Note that with the (soon to be released) gremlin-python 3.2.10/3.3.4 you can do `hasNext()` in Python directly and the above to options can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try `drop().iterate()` instead of `next()`